# Emoji characters in select list (dropdown) control appear washed-out in Chrome and Safari (but not Firefox) on Mac

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, chromium, emoji

I'm writing a select list (dropdown) control for a web page that will allow a user to select a skin tone.

Here's the relevant snippet of my HTML:

```html
  <select>
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value=""></option>
  </select>
```

This renders as expected in Firefox on Mac:

[image: Skin tone select dropdown - Firefox on Mac]

However, (also on Mac) in Chrome and in Safari, the colors on the items that are both unselected and unfocused/unhovered appear very "washed-out", such that it is difficult to properly distinguish their color:

[image: Skin tone select dropdown - Chrome on Mac]

What's the best workaround or solution to get the skin tone colors to appear properly in the latter browsers?

I'm using Bootstrap 4, so solutions using Bootstrap's CSS library are acceptable (in addition to plain HTML/CSS solutions).

So far I've tried:

- Setting the CSS `color` (foreground text color) attribute on the `select` and/or `option` elements;
- Setting the CSS `background-color` attribute on the `select` and/or `option` elements;
- Setting the CSS `opacity` attribute on the `select` and/or `option` elements;
- Setting `-webkit-appearance: none` on the `select` and/or `option` elements.

Comment: Oh the horror of discovering your exact problem on stack overflow and realising there is no answer! 